Can't understand a sentense in the text, and usage of "their"
the name of the book: "The Bell Jar".
the page: 1.
I bold the part I can't understand. Could someone help me with it? What does the author mean and what about "their"?
text:
It was a queer, sultry summer, the summer they electrocuted the Rosenbergs, and I didn't know what I was doing in New York. I'm stupid about executions. The idea of being electrocuted makes me sick, And that's all there was to read about in the papers-google-eyed headlines staring up at me on every street corner and at the fusty , peanut-smelling mouth of every subway . It had nothing to do with me, but I couldn't help wondering what it would be like, being burning alive all along your nerves.
I though it must be the worst thing in the world. New York was bad enough. By nine in the morning the fake, country-freshness that somehow seeped in overnight evaporated like the tail end of a sweet dream. Mirage-gray at the bottom of "THEIR" granite canyons, the hot streets wavered in the sun, the car tops sizzled and glittered, and the dry, cindery dust blew into my eyes and down my throat.

What do you think it means?

@BillJ Actually I don't understand what "Mirage-gray" is and who is "their" so it is impossible for me to understand.  If it was written like this: "Mirages at the bottom of granite canyons (do something or something happen with them)" it will be easy to understand.

'Their' refers to the streets, which are grey like mirages at the bottom of their granite canyons. The streets of New York and other cities with many high-rise building are often called canyons because they resemble steep sided canyons found in the ground.

This is 'poetic language'. The author, Sylvia Plath, is best known as a poet.

@michaelharvey Thanks.

@kateBunting I just didn't realize that this applies to the streets.

@KateBunting - I had a girlfriend in the 1980s who was very keen on Plath. Unhealthily so. I was reminded of her when I read a Medium  article titled 'Am I Depressed or Have I Been Reading Too Much Sylvia Plath?'

Compare:

With bells on their collars, cats are less likely to catch birds.

When the pronoun anticipates its noun, it is said to be "cataphoric".  Perhaps the example sentence will be mnemonic :-)

+1 for the cats
